# AngularJS inside MVC, preloading static HTML or MVC partial views to use @templateCache to make app offline?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, offline-caching, angular-templatecache

We have an MVC project with AngularJS sitting on top of it.
Question - is possible to preload static HTML files (partial templates) into **templateUrl** property for Angular's custom components or directives.

If it is possible, can I use Angular's **@templateCache** to make the project work offline?

The reason I am asking is that in all examples I have found, there is no MVC, just plain html folder structure.

But with MVC all requests to load a view go through MVC Controller's Action, that loads the view.

So, by specifying `templateUrl: 'mypartialview.html'` will do nothing since I dont have .html files, also there is no such path that will tell templateUrl where to look for a template.
by specifying `templateUrl: '/HomeController/mypartial/'` - can this be done? to get the partial view?

If yes, can I cache it using Angular's **@templateCache** to make the project work offline?

Thanks.